# COUNTIFS across two sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, countif

I am trying to use a COUNTIFS statement in Excel (version 2013)  in order to count the number of rows on a separate sheet that are between a date range specified in another.  The result is returning `0`, when in fact it should be `19`.

```
=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!P:P,">Sheet2!B2",'Sheet1'!P:P,"<Sheet2!D2")
```

Sheet1 Column P is a the given date for each row in Sheet1, and Sheet2 B2 and D2 are the start and end dates that I want to filter between.

Ideally, I would like to add the ability to filter the same date range on a second column of Sheet1 and third criteria.  "Count if the date range is between X and Y and Column A contains (Z)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,"Z",Sheet1!P:P,">"&Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!P:P,"<"&Sheet2!D2)
```

since the cell references are qualified with sheet names, should work in either sheet (or elsewhere!) but might be shortened if in one or other of Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!P:P,">" & Sheet2!B2,'Sheet1'!P:P,"<" & Sheet2!D2)
```